# Dynamic GET Request with Ajax and Django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm fairly new to using Ajax however have been using Django for a while now.

I'm wondering how I can submit a form dynamically which will - without refreshing the page - append this new 'parameter' to the URL and return some updated data. For example, if I change a value called maximum price and click 'Apply' then this will add '`&max_price=some_new_value`' to the URL and return the a Django queryset with the filter of maximum price.

I've been able to start like this...

```
$('.filter-ul-opt-change-apply').click(function(){
    $.get(...{
        ...
    })
})
```

although the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) specifies that a URL like `ajax/test.html` be passed as an argument into the `get()` method, but I'm unsure how this will work with a Django view to retrieve objects.

views.py:

```
def generic_view(request):
    objs = Objects.objects.filter(...parameters from updated url go here...)
    return render(request, 'generic-view.html', {'objs':objs})
```

Any ideas on using Django and Ajax for this purpose would be really useful!

Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be on the URL as get? Could't it be a post?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the URL at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman So that you can link that URL to others and when they visit the link they will see the list of objects with the filters that have been applied

Answer (score 1):

you could just use ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : yourDataType,
    data : {
     'max_price'=some_new_value
    }
    url : theUrlYouMappedServerSide,
    success : function(response) {
    }
});
```

and in your .py you should have something like :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse

def yourFunc(request):
    max_price= request.GET.get('max_price', None)
    //do some stuff
    data = {
        // your stuff from serverside
    }
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

and you should have a viewroute :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^theUrlYouMappedServerSide/$', views.yourFunc, name='yourFunc')
]
```

you'll just have to use something different from `HttpResponse(data)` depending on your needs

Comment: How is 'yourFunc' method accessed by the Ajax method if the url specified relates to the 'yourView' class? Just confused!

Comment: okay, as the action of the form right? e.g. action='specified_url'

Comment: either you hardcode the func in the form or you use the viewroute  `url(r'^theUrlYouMappedServerSide/$', views.yourFunc, name='yourFunc')`

Comment: if you use form, your ajax url must be : `url: form.attr("data-validate")` and the form : `<form method="get" data-validate="{% url 'yourFunc' %}">`

Answer (score 0):

AJAX generic request :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET", // or POST
        url: YOUR_ENDPOINT,
        data : YOUR_GET_PARAMETERS,
        success: function(response) {
             // success callback, update your html
        }, 
        error: function(response) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
```

And on django side use `request.GET` to treat your parameters

Comment: Thanks! Will the data section be a list of strings or variables? So say I have parameters min_price, max_price and category - would I write that as data:'min_price,max_price,category' etc or something different?

Comment: It's supposed to be a JS object `{'min_price': 0, 'max_price': ..., 'category': ..}`, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It'a a bit long to explain and surely a bit late for answering but maybe this will be useful for others in such a case : you should have a look at **HTMX**, it's fantastic. [The doc](https://htmx.org/examples/inline-validation/) is very good either.

But I learnt all the bases of HTMX with [this guy that produced very good videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ula0c_rZ6gk&list=PL-2EBeDYMIbRByZ8GXhcnQSuv2dog4JxY&ab_channel=BugBytes) on this subject.

He changed my life : no more need of AJAX or heavy other JS code everywhere.